# Help! Ubuntu doesnt boot

Tags: boot, kernel

So, I installed ubuntu a few months ago. It had loads of problems but with the help of forums I solved them. Today I turned on my notebook, used it for a while, it gave me a message of low battery, I closed the lid and when I went to open it, it had turned off. Now everytime I turn it on, it just stays at a screen with an underline (_) and I cant do anything. After a little while it displays this message:

```
INFO: task swapper/0:1 blocked for more than 120 seconds.  
         Not tainted 4.4.0-57-generic #78-Ubuntu  
   "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.  

INFO: task kworker/u8:0:6 blocked for more than 120 seconds.  
         Not tainted 4.4.0-57-generic #78-Ubuntu  
   "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
```

And keeps showing these messages.
Can someone help please?
Im using a Ubuntu 16.04LTS
I cant check the kernel, as it doesnt boot
My PC is a H-Buster and has 3840 RAM memory
My graphics card is a NVidia Geforce 91000M G with Cuda

Comment: What model notebook?

Comment: Please, provide detailed information about your system, like Ubuntu Version, Kernel, Laptop model, RAM, etc.

Answer (score 0):

When your notebook is booting, you should see the grub loader. It should look something like this

[image: Grub Boot Loader Image]

If you select "Advanced Options", you should be allowed to boot to a "recovery" section.

Please let me know if this allows the machine to boot.

Otherwise, you may need to re-insert the installation media, and select rescue a broken system.

Comment: After OP gets into his system via GRUB what next should please add this.

Comment: Starting a boot from recovery didnt work, shows a lot of messages, like if it was my computer, but without graphics, also I cant do anything. I tried using a installation media, and it just shows the same message from my post.

Comment: I have the same problem as gaius03. Booting from usb stick or trying recovery leads to the same error. @gaius03 did you find a solution?